# alternative to webclient.uploadstringasync for windows 8 metro style app in c#

Tags: c#, windows, post, httpclient, webclient

I am using Visual Studio Express 2012 RC to design my metro style app for windows 8.

In past, i developed an app for windows phone in which i used `webclient.uploadstringasync` to post a string data to the server. But as `webclient` is not present for windows 8, I am searching for it's alternative.

I tried using `httpclient.postasync` but it did not work (don't know why).

Can anyone suggest me what to do. Please explain whatever method you suggest and try to give an example. I am a beginner in c# so any help will work. Thanks

**Here is the code sample which i used with `httpclient.postasync` but not worked (don't know why).**

```
HttpClient data=new HttpClient();
HttpContent post;
async private void buttonupdate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    post=new StringContent("I put the string here which is to be posted");
    await data.PostAsync(URI,post);  
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried to use `HttpClient.PostAsync`? Can you give a code sample? It sounds like it is the alternative you're looking for.

Comment: @DanielSklenitzka updated the question with code sample..please help thanks

Comment: Is there any exception? What do you see in Fiddler?

Comment: @StephenCleary there is no error at all...the application is working perfectly fine but i cannot see any string posted to the server......i used the post method with webclient and it worked but with httpclient it is not wokring.......do i have to mention that i want to use post method in httpclient just like we have to do in webclient?

Comment: Have you declared the `internetClient` capability?

Comment: @StephenCleary problem solved...i was actually making a silly mistake...i was using a wrong uri by mistake to update.....anyways thanks to all who used some time to look at and reply here :)

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent("Put Your Data Here");
stringContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
stringContent.Headers.ContentLength = uriString.Length;
stringContent.Headers.ContentEncoding.Add("UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look in to BackgroundUploader Class for windows 8 it provides overloaded methods that might be helpful to achieve your requirement

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.networking.backgroundtransfer.backgrounduploader.aspx)

Comment: i don't think i should use this as i am just trying to upload a little string which would be of a kb....it is clearly written on the link you provided that i should only use this method if i want to upload files like music, video etc.

Comment: I Agree with you I was just giving you an alternate with out having the idea of how much data you will uploading. I am happy to delete my answer

Comment: no you don't have to delete your answer....now i have added the code sample in the question....can you now answer me?